# Clearing child divs from parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My divs are generated dynamically, I would like to do this:

```
<div class="MasterDiv">
<div class="ChildMasterDiv">10:39 D</div>
<div class="ChildMasterDiv1">10:39 D</div>
</div>
```

I would like to remove all of the child divs from the `<MasterDiv>`. I have tried

```
$('.MasterDiv div').empty();
```

but it did not work.

Comment: `$('.MasterDiv').empty();` ???  What's wrong with reading DOC, seriously?!

Comment: So read it, i cannot read it for you... If there is some other children different than DIVs you don't want to 'remove', use Sadikhasan's answer instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove all content inside MasterDiv.

```
$('.MasterDiv').empty();
```

When you are interested in removing only divs, then you should go with:

```
$('.MasterDiv div').remove();
```

Your example:

```
$('.MasterDiv div').empty();
```

will remove all content from all divs inside od MasterDiv. So it will only remove their content (11:39 D)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('.MasterDiv div').remove();
```

```js
$('.MasterDiv div').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MasterDiv">
  Hello
<div class="ChildMasterDiv">10:39 D</div>
<div class="ChildMasterDiv1">10:39 D</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why using jquery when a simple css line would be enough?

> .MasterDiv div {display:none;}

Answer (score 0):

**empty()** will remove all the contents of the selection.
**remove()** will remove the selection and its contents.